# The quadratic transformation of $\mathbb{P}^{2}$, $(a_{0},a_{1},a_{2})\mapsto (a_{1}a_{2},a_{0}a_{2},a_{0}a_{1})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{P}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^{2}$ defined by 
$$(a_{0},a_{1},a_{2})\mapsto (a_{1}a_{2},a_{0}a_{2},a_{0}a_{1}).$$
I am tasked to show tha this is a rational map. My goal is to show that $\varphi$ is represented by a morphism on the open set $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}:xyz\neq 0\}$. The only thing I have left to do is show that $\varphi$ is continuous. My idea is to show that $\varphi$ is closed that would mean that $\varphi^{-1}$ is continuous(I have already shown it exists and $\varphi^{-1}=\varphi$). I am stuck here. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: $\phi$ is polynomial ...

Comment: Of course. Thanks for the obvious poke.